# len container change, no such element Unable to locate element. Scraping tripadvisor review

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Please Help !! I want to scrape reviews of tourist destinations on the tripadvisor web. I get this code. but when executed there is an error on certain pages, and len(container) which was 11, on the error page changes to 12. then, an error appears:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath"," selector":".//div[@class='DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx']"}
```

Some code:

```
for i in range(from_page, num_page):
    print(f'halaman ke-{i+1}')

    # default tripadvisor website
    
    url = f"https://www.tripadvisor.co.id/Attraction_Review-g3177248-d2314079-Reviews-or{i}0-Benang_Stokal_and_Benang_Kelambu_Waterfall-Praya_Lombok_West_Nusa_Tenggara.html"
    
    # if you pass the inputs in the command line
    if (len(sys.argv) == 4):
        path_to_file = sys.argv[1]
        num_page = int(sys.argv[2])
        url = sys.argv[3]

    # Import the webdriver
    driver.get(url)
    # expand the review 
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[contains(@class, 'DrjyGw-P _1l3JzGX1')])")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

    first_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_1c8_1ITO']")
    container = first_container.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")

    
    print(len(container))

    for j in range(len(container)-1):
        
        text_review = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx']")
        review_text = text_review.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='_2tsgCuqy']").text.replace("\n", " ")
                
        csvWriter.writerow((review_text,))
    print('Selanjutnya -->')

driver.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to print that ? I'm getting all the text, all I did was `review_text = text_review.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='_2tsgCuqy']").text` and then print `review_text`

Comment: yes I understand. but here's the problem I want to take the review to the last page. in one page, the length of the container is 11 containers, the program has been running until page 5, but on page 6 the length of the container changes to 12, while in the program the condition "for j in range (len(container)-1)" is made because 10 containers last review and container for next page. while on the web the container structure still looks 11, on the error page and on the next page there are 12 containers. that's what makes me confused, what should i change and i add?